# Mac OS startup keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard-layout

I'm a Mac OS 10.8 newbie, and I would like to seek assistance on how to change the keyboard layout for my Mac.

In my account, chuacw, I have changed the keyboard layout to Dvorak, however, when I boot up the machine, it is still using US keyboard, until I log into my account, at which point, it becomes Dvorak.

I would like the Dvorak layout to be active even before I log into an account.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The only thing you need to do is check this box below:**

[image: Mac OS X System Preferences — Users & Groups, with the "Show Input menu in login window" checkbox checked]

That will give you a menu item in the top right corner of your login screen that says the current keyboard layout, and allows you to change it.

[image: Mac OS X Login Screen with the Input Menu activated]

As a bonus, you also get an input menu any time you need to type your password to authorize a change to your Mac.

[image: Mac OS X system change authorization dialog box, with Input Menu activated]

IIRC, once I chose my keyboard layout of choice ([Colemak](http://colemak.com/)) in either of these places it remembered it for future logins.

Enjoy

Comment: Using this you're forced to change the layout every single time you restart, and your preferred layout likely requires scrolling through the entire list each time.

Answer (score 3):

1. Run `sudo rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone; sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/Setup\ Assistant.app/Contents/MacOS/Setup\ Assistant`
2. Select the input method (custom keyboard layouts have to be in the root library)

   [image]
3. Fill in anything in the remaining steps
4. Delete the created account in the Users & Groups preferences
5. Change the computer name back in the Sharing preferences

[A similar question at Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44913/make-a-custom-keyboard-layout-the-system-default-on-lion-even-for-the-login-sc)